# Angular - Interpolate string with html

Tags: angularjs, string-interpolation

So i've got a "template string" that looks like this:

```
var templateString = "Hello my name is {{name}}";
```

The name that I want to interpolate is a in variable. So I proceeded this way:

```
var miniScope = {
 name: "Chuck"
};

var sentence = $interpolate(templateString)(miniScope);
/* sentence: "Hello my name is Chuck" */
```

This works. Now I'd like to **bold** the name. I've obviously tried:

```
var miniScope = {
 name: "<strong>Chuck</strong>"
};
```

But the html code gets escaped. Any idea how I can achieve this?

PS: For those of you who wonder why I don't just put the string in the template, it's because my template string is coming from the server.

Answer (score 16):

This [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N9nnb3XzniIC1vStChZ2) outputs "Hello my name is **Chuck**" as expected.  The JavaScript is unchanged from the question.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);
app.controller("TestCtrl", TestCtrl);
function TestCtrl($scope, $interpolate) {
  var templateString = "Hello my name is {{name}}";

  var miniScope = {
    name: "<strong>Chuck</strong>"
  };

  $scope.sentence = $interpolate(templateString)(miniScope);
}
```

And in your HTML, make use you use `ng-bind-html` to keep the HTML from being encoded.

```
  <body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-bind-html="sentence"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: @PardeepJain No, `ng-bind-html` doesn't work in Angular 2. You need to use `[innerHTML]` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711797/1990505) answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this directive to compile stuff from the string.

```
.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
            element.html(value);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    );
};
}])


$scope.name = "Vladimir";
$scope.str = "Hello my name is <strong>{{name}}</strong>";


<div compile="str"></div>
```

and use $sce to compile trusted html if You need [Angular $sce doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

but all of this stuff not angular way actualy, You have to use some different partials and include it with ng-include directive.

Comment: I actually ended up doing this in a completely different way. I'll leave the post in case this helps someone else. Thanks for your reply