# angularjs string variable to html element

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS code:

```
$scope.checking="<div style="color:red;">check</div>";
```

HTML code:

```
{{checking}}
```

Result in HTML page in browser:

```
<div>check</div>
```

Now what I want is that the `$scope.checking` variable be parsed in HTML as if it's a tag I defined.

So the result in html page should be:

```
check
```

and the above should come in red color

Any way to do it? hopefully its simple... AngularJS experts please help!

i got the output but the string doesnt come in red! the style tag is ignored! how can i do it? do i use interpolate?

Comment: Did you declare `ng-model="checking"`? I am a little confused on what you are asking.

Comment: angularjs and evrything works fine...evrything is declared and angularjs perfectly....

Comment: Perhaps you can post a line from your Code. This would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular - Interpolate string with html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291864/angular-interpolate-string-with-html)

Comment: why would you do something like that with n number of ways available to counter anything as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-bind-html`!
Here is the docs-page for `ng-bind-html`. This will help you.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

`ng-bind-html` will render your html-string in the browser.
Perhaps you have to "trust"  your html string like here: http://erikaugust.com/thoughts/ng-bind-html/

Comment: I think he just wants to print out the value of checking.