# Angular2 - Interpolate string with html

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How to Interpolate string with html using angular2. i know in angular 1.x there is `$interpolate(templateString)(miniScope);` but i haven't find the same for angular2.

suppose i have a template like this : `Hello my name is {{name}}`

and binding is like `name: "<strong>Pardeep</strong>"`

so i want result like

> Hello my name is **Pardeep**

[Refer for angular1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291864/angular-interpolate-string-with-html)

[for angular2 see here but i'm unable to understand clearly](https://github.com/PawelGerr/angular2-interpolation)

any help ?

Answer (score 55):

You can simply use `[innerHTML]` directive to accomplish it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6x04QSKhqbDwPvdsLSL9?p=preview

```js
import {Component, Pipe} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
            Hello my name is <span [innerHTML]="myName"></span> 
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

  myName='<strong>Pardeep</strong>';

}
```

**Update:**

I checked it doesn't work this way after **RC.1** release.

Let's say to make it work with **RC.4** you can use `DomSanitizationService` as shown below,

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="myCheckbox"></div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {

  dangerousUrl='<input type="checkbox">';

  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {

    this.myCheckbox= sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.dangerousUrl);
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yexm1Mf8B3FRhNch3EMz?p=preview

Comment: i know, and what in case of if `myName='<input type="checkbox">';` ?

Comment: Check now it works with `DomSanitizationService` API.

Comment: innerHTML still works and you don't want to trust html unless you really really have too... Look at the documentation under 'Content Security' 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings