# String interpolation inside innerHTML in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How can I render an expression inside an `[innerHTML]` directive:

```ts
public stringInterpolation: string = 'title';
public data: any = '<a>{{stringInterpolation}}</a>';
```

```html
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

String interpolation is being rendered as text not the exact value.

Logic behind this is I am using a reusable table and I want a configuration where in I can specify a template that will be generated inside a cell rather than listing all data as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Interpolate string with html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279071/angular2-interpolate-string-with-html)

Comment: Sorry. but i am looking for a way to read the value of a string interpolation inside the innerHtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use TypeScript interpolation. Angular bindings aren't supported in dynamically added HTML:

```
public data: any = `<a>${stringInterpolation}</a>`;
```

Comment: You should be aware that this only binds a single time when `data` is initialized in contrary to `{{}}` which updates every time `stringInterpolation` changes.

Comment: sir can you tell mw how to iterate array with TypeScript interpolation?.actually i have an array like this---*ngFor="let item of ${salesOrderModel.SalesOrderItemList}"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, if you have to inject different templates inside an html tag. You have to create one component for each template you need, and load components dynamically.

To load component at runtime, see this: [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)