# Replace dynamically inserted keywords with user data angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm not exactly sure what to call this so I might have missed some things in my search for an answer for this but basically I have data that comes in from an external api and it gets inserted into an `innerHTML` tag now in the data that is being returned is some html which then gets processed thanks to `innerHTML` but I have certain keywords in the returned html like this `[username]` and I want to replace that with data I have stored. So in my **.ts** file I might have..

```
username: 'name';
```

then in my html I have

```
<div class='inner-html' [innerHTML]="data.html"></div>
```

and in my response from `data.html` the html is like so

```
<h1>Hey [userName] lorem ipsum...</h1>
```

so I want to replace the `[userName]` that comes in dynamically from the external api with the username that is stored in `username`

I tried to put `{{username}}` in the html that is coming in.. but that didnt work and I also tried `${username}` but that also didnt work..

Im wondering if there is another way?

**EDIT** 
Ive tried to use str.replace(); in the onChanges life cycle event but that isn't working either my code is ..

```
  const html = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.inner-html');
  html.innerHTML.replace('[userName]', this.username);
```

Now something like this must be possible, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String interpolation inside innerHTML in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780643/string-interpolation-inside-innerhtml-in-angular-2)

Comment: @Narm its a different question and that post doesnt have a clear answer anyway

Comment: @A61NN5 - please check my answer, I think you'll be pleased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides the Pipe precisely for this purpose:

> Pipe
>
> An Angular pipe is a function that transforms input values to output
>   values for display in a view.

They provide *reusable* and *scalable* ways of accomplishing your goal. Please check this out as I think it is what you are after:

[Live Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nedchs?file=app%2Fparse-inner-html.pipe.ts)

Basically, you pipe the output of the `[innerHTML]` through a transform:

```
<div class='inner-html' [innerHTML]="data.html | parseInnerHtml:replacements"></div>
```

`parseInnerHtml` is the custom pipe and it takes a hash of replacement keys and corresponding values to replace with:

```
import { Input, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'parseInnerHtml'})
export class ParseInnerHtml implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: string, replacements: Object): string {
    let search = Object.keys(replacements);
    for(let i = 0; i < search.length; i++){
      text = text.replace('['+ search[i] +']', replacements[search[i]]);
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should modify you replacement method so that it works if the string to replace is there more than one time

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'll allow the OP to do that if so desired. I've answered the question as asked.

Comment: @Randy Casburn Hey there just one quick question.. this works perfectly but.. Im getting an error in the console that says `cannot convert undefined or null to object on line 5 of the parseInnerHtml pipe` Im assuming this is because the data hasnt come in yet before this call is made.. is there anyway to avoid this??

Comment: That sounds like you didn't create an object that has the replacements. this is shown in the solution in app.component.ts @ line 9. Did you create?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have control of the dynamic data. If that is so, It would make more sense if you could transform the html on the server to include the `username`.

However if you don't have control, you could easily use replace the `[username]` with what you have. E.G:

`str.replace('[username]', this.username);`

Comment: The question was how to accomplish this with Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- in hello.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: ``,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() username: string;

  private _html: string;
  @HostBinding('innerHTML')
  @Input() set html(html: string) {
    this._html = html.replace('[userName]', this.username);
  }

  get html() {
     return this._html;
  }
}

-- in app.component.html
<hello [html]="html" [username]="username"></hello>

-- in app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  username = 'App user';
  html = '<h1>Hello [userName]!</h1>';
}
```

[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hchpcn)