# str.replace() does not exist on 'HTMLElement' Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular app, On init I want to check if there are any keywords and if there are replace them with data I have stored.. but when I do

```
const innerHtml = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.inner-html');
innerHtml.replace(...);
```

I get this error  `[ts] Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`

How can I use str.replace() in typescript??

Ive looked around and I cant find any reference to .replace() and this error

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.querySelector` returns an HTML [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), in order to get its inner HTML you'd have to access its [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property, you would then need to re-assign that to `innerHTML`:

```
// this selects an element with CSS class "inner-html"
const element = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.inner-html');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(...);
```

Note that this is not how you would update elements in Angular. Angular works with components and you'd bind a property to a component rather than imperatively select and update the text (Angular does that part for you). Consider reading [the introduction guide](https://angular.io/tutorial).

Comment: The reason Im doing it this way is because the content is dynamically loaded from an api, so If it was on my actual page I would just use interpolation

Comment: @A61NN5 you should consider loading the text via Angular's HTTP service - and then `.subscribing` to the HTTP request and assigning a property on your model there - any change to a property would _automatically_ update components bound to it (aka "data binding").

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374349/replace-keywords-with-user-data-angular-5 I asked this same question here, if you could look there and see if what you say applies and answer I would be very thankful

Comment: Those answers are confusing because the "possible duplicate" is about creating _dynamic_ html and not data. See https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/ as an example

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting has nothing to do with Typescript. You are using `document.querySelector()` to capture an element in the DOM. That, in turn, returns a `HTMLElement` object. That object is not a String.

If you want the atual innerHTML of the element, you should use:

```
const innerHtml = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.inner-html').innerHTML;
```

That should give you a string with the contents of the element. A String has the `replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Query selector returns a Node. And you need access Node.innerHml

```
const innerHtml = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.inner-html');
innerHtml.innerHmtl.replace(...);
```