# Render dynamic interpolation in angular 2/7 (like rendering cellTemplate in ui grid)

Tags: angular, ui-grid, dynamicgridview

want use a cell templates for my dynamic data table in angular 7 like ui grid cell template. kindly anybody help me

**cell template:**

```
sampleCellTemplate = `<div>city:{{row[field.address.city]}}</div>
<div>zipcode:{{row[field.address.zipcode]}}</div>`
```

**usage:**

```
<span  *ngIf="!field.cellTemplate; else withCellTemplate">
    {{row[field.name]}}
  </span>
  <ng-template #withCellTemplate>
    <span [innerHTML]="field.cellTemplate"></span>
  </ng-template>
```

[**my stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fm5hpx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String interpolation inside innerHTML in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780643/string-interpolation-inside-innerhtml-in-angular-2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i gone through the suggested older solutions, but in my case, interpolation is not static, if I change to ${row[field.name]}, row and field are undefined. Kindly check my stackblitz demo