# How to render a HTML string with a directive

Tags: angular, pipe, popover, ngx-bootstrap, contentful

I have a use case where I need to render and transform an HTML node to HTML string and then add a ngx-bootstrap tooltip directive on a specific element in that that HTML string.

I can get the HTML to render fine, by either using InnerHTML with a pipe or creating a separate component, but always after the HTML is rendered the tooltip directive on the element is not registered and I'm not sure where to go from here. I would have though using `pure: false` on the PIpe would solved it, but it does not.

Here is what've I tried with a pipe:

### The Pipe With Tooltip Directive

```
import { documentToHtmlString } from '@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BLOCKS, INLINES } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { DeckState } from '../__states/deck';

@Pipe({ name: 'rich', pure: false })
export class RichContent implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private store: Store) {
  }

  transform(content) {


    let options = {
      renderNode: {
        [INLINES.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node) => {
          return `<b [tooltip]="node.data.target.fields.companyName">${node.data.target.fields.companyName}</b>`
        }
      }
      }

      var html = documentToHtmlString(content, options);

      return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);

  }
}
```

### The HTML

```
<div [innerHTML]="content | rich"></div>
```

### Outcome

Plain HTML without the tooltip directive working or being registered.
For example:

```
<p>Here is an example from <b [tooltip]="node.data.target.fields.companyName">Mixpanel</b></p>
```

Hope someone can help me and point me in the right direction to solve this.

Comment: from the top of my head.. I think you can't for security reasons, you need to write a component. check [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding) if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation where I was trying to use ngStyle with content I had rendered using innerHTML and my finding (though I'd happily be proven wrong) was that it wasn't possible, because the innerHTML content isn't interpolated by Angular. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42780824/2627160).

The solution in my case was to add the necessary styling at source (server-side) rather than with Angular.

Could you just use a [title HTML attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp)? Not going to look as nice as Angular but if it's just a tooltip you're after, it might do the trick?

Though as [rmjoia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3459011/rmjoia) suggests, you'd be better off pulling the data you need into a new component and then adding styling, tooltips etc. as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can't for security reasons, you need to write a component.

Check [Angular 2 innerHTML (click) binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676726/angular-2-innerhtml-click-binding) same issue, different case though..

[Security](https://angular.io/guide/security)
[Sanitization example](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example)