# Angular 2 + string with <br>

Tags: pipe

I have a simple Interface Blog that store a text as string. My string have a `<br>` inside for a new line.

In my template i try to do `<h1>{{blog.text}}</h1>`. I get a security message.

How can I solve my problem in a simple way?

Comment: provide some code that you've tried.

Comment: here is my simple setup:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Interpolate string with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279071/angular2-interpolate-string-with-html)