# Importing html-/ts-file in Angular 7

Tags: angular, import, angular7

I am creating a code demo in Angular 7, where I would like to have panes for showing a component example - in this view you could see the 'result', as well as the code behind it. I made a Stackblitz, where I am able to import the HTML-file into the ts-file, so it can be displayed as raw HTMl. For the actual use case, I have a child component I would like to use and show HTML for in the main component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/unparsed-html

However, when I try to replicate this in VS Code, it can't find the file, and I am stumped as to why. Any input or alternative methods is appreciated.

EDIT: I solved the initial question as noted in my answer, but I have a related question as well. I would like to show the content of the demo-components ts-file. Is it possible in any way to import this as a string?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: `<div [innerHTML]="htmlContent"></div>` Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279071/angular2-interpolate-string-with-html

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, `innerHTML` would suffer sanitization. Since this is a Code Example, I think the OP wants to show raw code. `innerText` would make more sense in this case.

Comment: innerHTML will not work as @SiddAjmera pointed out, as I wanted the raw unparsed HTML.

Comment: @SiddAjmera - no errors in console, as it doesn't compile because of the 'missing' file:

error TS2307: Cannot find module './action-menu-demo-example-code.component.html'.

It refers to it as a module in VS Code, though, is there some parameter I could set to import it in a another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to achieve the wanted result. I export the html as a string const, which I import and use as the template for the example-code-component. The same string can be imported in the demo-component, shown as a raw string. I will have to beautify it, but it works. If anyone knows how I can make the initial way I pictured work I would be very happy though! :)