# How to fix json html tag to text converter in angular 7

Tags: html, json, angular7

json data is coming from rest API with html tag like

```
(content: {rendered: "<p><strong>Destination Covered:</strong> Lorem Ipsum; Dolor</p>↵", protected: false})
```

how we convert HTML tag to text in angular7

`{{x.content.rendered}}` in angular 7

```
<p><strong>Destination Covered:</strong> Lorem Ipsum; Dolor</p>
```

display code in HTML format

The result should without HTML tag in angular6-7

Destination Covered: Lorem Ipsum; Dolor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Interpolate string with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279071/angular2-interpolate-string-with-html)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this ? Worked for me

```
          var f = '<p><strong>Destination Covered:</strong> Lorem Ipsum; Dolor</p> ';
        var e = document.createElement("div");
        e.innerHTML = f;
        document.getElementById("foo").innerText = e.innerText;
```

Please do leme know

Comment: this for a single element(ID), Data is coming from json file and we have to add code in angular loop.

Comment: use filter pipe /pipe function somethig using above logic

Comment: @OmPrakash you can use property databinding  check my answer 

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use databinding for innerHTML like this

*componenet*

```
hello = "<h1>Hello from  </h1>"
```

*template*

```
<div [innerHTML]="hello"></div>
```

[**demo** ‍♂️](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytz2sp)

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution:

```
in the file ts 
 bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text: string) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text)
  }

and in the html you should implement this html code :
                <p> <span [innerHTML]="bypassSecurityTrustHtml(myForm.value.pageContent)"></span></p>
    enter code here
```