# How to render HTML which is in array in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have a array in which one of the object contains HTML element. I wanted to render it in angular.

This is the array:

```
{
name: "rules", 
key: "rules", 
value_before: "<tr><td>revisit_in_some_days</td><td>less_then</td>td>r.input_data</td>"
}
```

I've tried multi for loops for angular.

I want table of the response in angular frontened.

Comment: Note that the HTML in there is malformed (`</td>td>` - typo?) and incomplete (part of a [HTML table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)).

Comment: you have typing mistakes near less_then</td>. unopened td tag. and missing closing tr tag

Comment: Yes, It is there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Interpolate string with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279071/angular2-interpolate-string-with-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use `[innerHTML]` directive that comes with angular.
Usage:

```
data = [
  {
    value_before: '<div>some content</div>'
  },
  {
    value_before: '<div>some content1</div>'
  }
];
```

in your .html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  <div [innerHTML]="item.value_before"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to give style to the array object and it will render at the front?

Comment: it is, you can have it as object that would follow up `[ngStyle]` directive like `[ngStyle]="{'color': '#fff'}"`. This means that you could have in you object property `style` and have new object in it as `style: {'color': '#fff'}` so you can use it in your template like `<div [innerHTML]="item.value_before" [ngStyle]="item.style"></div>`. Hope that i explained it right, if not let me know in private or write a new question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

you should use [innerHTML] directive that comes with angular by default. Like:

`<ul><li *ngFor="let res of trackLogList[key]" [innerHTML]="res"></li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will be placing the HTML inside a table,you can use`[innerHtml]` in `table`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of yourArray">
  <table [innerHTML]="item.value_before"></table>
</div>
```