# How to Interpolate the Tag Name in Angular Template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I've some api data..Html Markup in Json format:

```
[
  {
     type: 'p',
     attributes: [...],
     children: [{...},{...}]
  }
]
```

I would like to render that in an angular template. 
Since the name of the tag come from the api, i need to interpolate the tag name.

i tried this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let el of body">
   <{{el.type}}> foo bar</{{el.type}}>
</ng-container>
```

but got "Unexpected closing tag "{{el.type}}".

expected output:

```
<p> foobar</p>
```

And I don't want to use innerHtml directive.

Comment: Its an array of object. Try {{el[0].type}} to get the first type of el object

Comment: updated the snippet. I'm already at the object level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Interpolate string with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279071/angular2-interpolate-string-with-html)

Comment: i want to use the type property as html tag

Comment: Why don't you want to use `[innerHTML]`? I know one possible reason but I would like to know what your reason is...

Comment: there are multiple reasons for that. it's hard to use directives or bindings on innerHtml. styling is a pain (ng-deep) and so on. Last but not least, i don't think it's reasonable to generate a whole page in a service or component , if you've a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

construct your html inside js assign it to local variable and finally pass that value into innerhtml it will render as you expected

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [innerHTML] directive to accomplish it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [textContent] if you don't want to use [innerHTML].

Comment: You will not be able to render HTML content on the DOM using `textContent`.

Comment: Yes, It can only display the content