# Render html string within a template using interpolation?

Tags: angular

Using Angular 4.3.0

Say I have a string like this that is a property of a component.

```
<p>test#2 bla bla</p><p>test1234 56</p><p>test test</p>
```

So, Im following along with the docs, 
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#property-binding-or-interpolation-

This does not work:
What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let b of BlogPostList">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{b.Title}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <span style="text-align:left">Created:{{b.DateCreated | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span><span style="text-align:right">Last updated{{b.DateUpdated | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
            <br/>
            <div [innerHTML]="<b>test here</b>"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token < at column 1 in [<b>test here</b>] in ...</span>
                <br/>
                <div [ERROR ->][innerHTML]="<b>test here</b>"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to pass your `[innerHTML]` as a string wrap it with single quotes, 
`<div [innerHTML]="'<b>test here</b>'"></div>`

Comment: I assigned the [innerHTML] like this `[innerHTML]="'{blog.description}'"` . This is giiving a error. - `Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in `

Comment: @YoYo, in your case it should be just `[innerHTML]="blog.description}"` give that a try.

Comment: <div [innerHTML] = "video_banner.LongDesc"></div>

Answer (score 4):

You shoud write the parameter as a string.

```
 <div [innerHTML]="'test here'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if u want to use the parameter:

```
<div [innerHTML]="test.message"></div>
```